# How to find the expected number of insertions before a Hash table is full?

Tags: probability, expected-value

If I have a hash table with $m$ slots and each slot has $1/m$ probability of being picked for an insertion of an element. What is the expected number of insertions before all slots are full?

[image: slots]

I would think that the expected number of insertions of elements is $m$ but not sure because an element can also hash to another element's slot? Reason for this thought is: $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_x^{m}Pr[X=x] = \sum_x^{m}\frac{1}{m}=1$$
Where after $m$ insertions where each insertion has $1/m$ probability, the hash table is full. I don't care about what to do with the elements that collide. For simplicity sake we can just discard them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem seems relevant. (Also, as a side note, a conventional hash table implementation will never be full because it will be grown when you get close, and crash when it has no more room to grow.)

Comment: "I would think that the expected number of insertions of elements is $m$" The **minimal possible** number of insertions to fill the table is $m$. If there are any collisions (assuming you don't place those somewhere else in the same table), you get more than $m$ insertions.

Comment: oh yes. m must be the minimal number. Going to take a look at the the problem you just suggested.

Comment: @Arthur it makes sense.
What would happen if I add the following: What is the expected number of insertions if I had two different hash tables to choose from? Let's say that picking either one of the two tables has probability of $\frac{1}{m}$. I.e. What would be the exp. # insertions before any of the two hash tables gets full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is well-known as [Coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), so that the expected number of insertions until all slots are full is:
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=m H_m
$$
where $H_m$ is the harmonic number:
$$
H_m=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1k.
$$

Comment: nice. What if I add the following: What would be the expected number of insertions if I had two different hash tables to choose from? Let's say that picking either one of the two tables has probability of $\frac{1}{2}$. I.e. What would be the exp. # insertions before any of the two hash tables gets full?

Comment: Probably you mean "has probability of $\frac12$", don't you?

Comment: yes sorry. ofc: $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: That is an interesting problem. I would suggest you to ask it in a separate question. You can even generalize and ask about $n$ tables (each being chosen with probability $\frac1n$).