# Expected number of elements before 1 out of 2 hash tables are full?

Tags: probability, expected-value, harmonic-numbers, coupon-collector

From a [previous asked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4047136/1508) it became clear to me that the expected number of elements to fill up one hash table (assuming ideal randomness) is just the Harmonic number: $mH_m$ where $m$ is the size of the table (collisions could just be solved with chaining or whatever. Don't care.)

**However, a more tricky question is:**

What is the expected number of elements we need before one of the hash tables are full? I.e. I want to know how fast it takes before one of the tables are full. We can assume that choosing either table $a$ or $b$ has probability $P[a|b]= \frac{1}{2}$ (see figure below).

[image: choosing either one]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be an elegant explanation of the result, but here is the bruteforce calculation.

---

We fix $m$ and define $E(a, b)$ as the expected number of elements to fill one table, if there are still $a$ and $b$ empty entries in the two tables.

Thus $E(0, *) = E(*, 0) = 0$ and we are looking for $E(m, m)$.

For $a, b > 0$, by considering the possibilities of the next element, we have: $$E(a, b) = 1 + \frac a {2m}E(a - 1, b) + \frac b {2m} E(a, b - 1) + (1 - \frac{a + b}{2m})E(a, b)$$ which simplifies to: $$(a + b) E(a, b) = 2m + aE(a - 1, b) + bE(a, b - 1).$$

If we define $F(a, b) = \frac 1 {2m} E(a, b)$, then we have the recurrence relation $$(a + b) F(a, b) = 1 + aF(a - 1, b) + bF(a, b - 1).$$

---

It is not totally obvious, but one can show by induction that $F(a, b) = H_a + H_b - H_{a + b}$ for all $a, b \geq 0$, where $H_n = \frac 1 1 + \dots + \frac 1 n$ denotes the harmonic number.

Proof: We simply need to verify that $$(a + b)(H_a + H_b - H_{a + b}) = 1 + a(H_{a - 1} + H_b - H_{a + b - 1}) + b(H_a + H_{b - 1} - H_{a + b - 1})$$ which is a routine calculation.

---

Therefore we have $F(m, m) = 2H_m - H_{2m}$ and hence $$E(m, m) = 2m F(m, m) = 4mH_m - 2mH_{2m}.$$

Comment: I realize that I made a mistake in the question. It's now updated: I am interested in knowing what the expected number of elements that are needed for at least one of the hash tables gets full. I.e. How fast we can fill up one table.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever I have updated the answer to target your updated question.

Comment: I am not sure that I undertand your calculations. I am having trouble understanding what you mean by $E(a,b)$, $E(*,0)$ and $E(m,m)$.

Comment: Let's say your tables are already partly filled. There are still $a$ empty entries in the first table, and $b$ empty entries in the second table. From this status, how many more elements are expected until one of the tables is full? This expected number is called $E(a, b)$. Then $E(*, 0) = 0$ means that $E(a, 0) = 0$ for any $a$. And $E(m, m)$ is the expected number from the original status, i.e. both tables have $m$ empty entries.

Comment: ah okay. Can you explain more on what's going on here: $E(a, b) = 1 + \frac a {2m}E(a - 1, b) + \frac b {2m} E(a, b - 1) + (1 - \frac{a + b}{2m})E(a, b)$

Comment: If $a, b > 0$, then you need to add at least one more element (this is the $1+$ on the right hand side). There are three possibilities. If the element goes into one of the $a$ empty entries in the first table, then the status becomes $(a - 1, b)$ and you expect $E(a - 1, b)$ more elements to finish. This happens with probability $\frac a {2m}$, hence contributing $\frac a {2m}E(a - 1, b)$ to the result. Same for $b$. And if the element doesn't go to any of the empty entries, then the status remains $(a, b)$.

Comment: wow. makes sense. However, I am not sure about the Harmonic numbers you derive?

Comment: It's a [proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) on $a + b$.

Comment: Okay. I would need to go through it step by step to understand it to the bones. But thank you.

Comment: How did you find the "not totally obvious" formula for $F(a,b)$?

Comment: @user I did it the stupid way. I listed out the values of $F(a, b)$ for small $a, b$ and found formulas for $F(1, b), F(2, b), F(3, b)$. At this moment I noticed the general formula. Proving it by induction is of course much easier.

Answer (score 2):

At the prompting of @user, I wanted to give an intuitive explanation of the formula found the in other answer.

Let $T_1$ be the time it takes to fill the first hash table, and $T_2$ be the time it takes to fill the second. You want $E[\min(T_1,T_2)]$. Since $\min(T_1,T_2)=T_1+T_2-\max(T_1,T_2)$, this is the same as
$$
E[T_1]+E[T_2]-E[\max(T_1,T_2)]
$$
Note that $\max(T_1,T_2)$ is the time it takes to fill out both hash tables, which is just like filling out a single larger hash table with size $2m$. Therefore, $E[\max(T_1,T_2)]=2m H_{2m}$, using what you already knew.

Symmetry implies $E[T_1]=E[T_2]$, but what is $E[T_1]$? It is not the same as the single hash table problem, since only about half of the hashes contribute to the first table. If every hash went to the first table, the expected time would be $mH_m$, so it stands to reason the expected time when you are going at half-speed should be $2mH_m$. This can be made rigorous using Wald's equation and an appropriate stochastic process, but hopefully this is at least believable.

Putting this altogether, you get $E[\min(T_1,T_2)]=2mH_m+2mH_m-2mH_{2m}$, as in the other answer.

Comment: nice. This one makes a bit more sense. But I have a couple of questions: 1. Why do you subtract $\mathbb{E}[max(T_1,T_2)]$ from the equation?   2. Since I am not well-versed in recurrence relations, could your answer above be as good as the first answer? I mean, the logic behind makes more sense to me.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever 1. It’s just a trick that happens to work. It comes from the general fact $\min(x,y)=x+y-\max(x,y)$ for any real numbers $x,y$. 2. My answer can be made rigorous, just as valid as the other. I think it would be a big pain to write out the details, but my outline could be fleshed out by anyone with sufficient knowledge of probability theory.