# Intuition behind the coupon collector problem. Is there inclusion-exclusion principle in play?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value, inclusion-exclusion, coupon-collector

As [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) the expected number of coupons $N$ required to collect the complete set of $n$ coupons in the general case of non-uniform probability distribution can be computed as:
$$
\mathbb E (N)=\sum_i\frac1{p_i}-\sum_{(i,j)}\frac1{p_i+p_j}+\sum_{(i,j,k)}\frac1{p_i+p_j+p_k}-\cdots-\frac{(-1)^n}{\underbrace{p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_n}_{=1}},\tag1
$$
where $p_i$ is the probability to obtain $i$-th coupon.

My question is: can this pattern be explained on the basis of the inclusion-exclusion principle? It really strikes that the first term $\frac1{p_i}$ is nothing else as the expected number of coupons till obtaining the $i$-th coupon, next term $\frac1{p_i+p_j}$ is the expected number of coupons till obtaining the $i$-th or the $j$-th coupon and so on.

I am looking for intuitively understandable explanation which would be consistent with the above interpretation of the separate terms.

I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: I'm not sure if that helps (sorry if not), but a while ago I considered a similar question in the context of the birthday paradox (why average group of people + random person = still average group of people). You may find my considerations at ResearchGate https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333150017_On_the_average_number_of_birthdays_in_birthday_paradox_setup  . There is a subsection "coupon collector's problem" and an appendix with the rigorous proof.

Comment: @guest Thank you very much.I will have a look on it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is exactly inclusion exclusion. For each $t\in \mathbb N_0$ and $k\in [n]$, let

- $E_t$ be the event that not all the coupons have been collected after $t$ coupons have been drawn,
- $E_{k,t}$ be the event that coupon $k$ does not appear in the first $t$ coupons.

Then $E_t=\bigcup_{k=1}^n E_{k,t}$, so inclusion-exclusion applies. It all comes together with these three pieces:
$$
E[N]=\sum_{t\ge 0}P(E_t),\\
P(E_{t})=\sum_{S\subseteq [n]} (-1)^{|S|+1}P\left(\bigcap_{k\in S} E_{k,t}\right),\\
P\left(\bigcap_{k\in S} E_{k,t}\right)=\left(1-\sum_{k\in S}p_k\right)^t.
$$
To be clear, $S$ ranges over only nonempty subsets of $[n]$.

Comment: Perfect, as usual. :)

Comment: Mike, could you have a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4051328. I am quite sure that it can be solved using the PIE in almost the same way as you demonstrated. The only problem is that underlying probabilities are not explicitly given. However I have strong impression that this is not required and the method can be applied even without this information provided the recipes for calculating the corresponding expected values are known.

Comment: @user I gave an answer, check it out. I think you can actually do something similar here; if you let $T$ be the time it takes to collect all coupons, and $T_k$ to get coupon $k$, then 
$$
T=\max(T_1,\dots,T_n)=\sum_S (-1)^{|S|-1}\min_{k\in S} T_k,
$$
where that crazy formula is just the generalization of $\max(T_1,T_2)=T_1+T_2-\min(T_1,T_2)$. Note all the $\min_S T_k$ variables are simple geometric r.v's.