# The number of distinct samples to get distinct integers

Tags: probability

Consider the integers $\{1,\dots, N\}$ for some large $N$.  Let us suppose that for each $\{1, \dots, n\}$ there are associated probabilities $p_1, \dots, p_n$ with $n \ll N$.

We sample independently and repeatedly from  $\{1,\dots, N\}$. For each $i \leq n$ we sample the integer $i$ with probability $p_i$.  With probability $q= 1-\sum_{1}^np_i$ we sample some integer greater than $n$. We are not concerned with which integer in this case.

After $s$ samples, we can you compute the expected number of distinct integers less than or equal to $n$ that have been sampled. [This is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061399/a-coupon-collector-related-problem-with-distinct-probabilities)

$$n-\sum_{i=1}^n(1-p_i)^s.$$

However I would like only to count the number of distinct samples.  So, imagine I sample uniformly and independently as before but I only stop once I have sampled $s$ distinct values. At that point, what is the expected number of distinct values will are less than or equal to $n$?

As an example, say $N=10$, $n=3$ and we want $5$ distinct samples. If the samples are $\{1,5,1,1,2, 5, 6, 2, 3\}$ then we have found all three values less then or equal to $n$.

Comment: @lulu Is it clearer now?

Comment: Not really.  I don't see how it could be answered without knowing the individual probabilities for integers $>n$.  As I say, a numerical example should help.  Or perhaps I am just not thinking clearly this morning.  In any case, good luck!

Comment: @lulu you may be right that you need to know those.  That would be interesting in itself.

Comment: So we can assume that the probabilities of all $N $ integers are known?

Comment: @user Yes if that is necessary. This is actually a practical question and $N$ will be large so if we can avoid using all of the probabilities that would be best but that may not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this without knowing the probability of every number, including those  $>n$. We can view this as an absorbing Markov chain. The states are all sets of at most $s$ numbers from $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$.  Those with cardinality $s$ are absorbing, and those with smaller cardinality are transient.

However, the chain is non-recurrent in the sense that once it leaves a state, it never returns to it, so we don't have to use matrices.  For a single set $\{x\}$ the probability that it will be visited at some time is the probability that $x$ is the first sample, or $p_x$.  For a doubleton $\{x,y\}$, the probability that it will be $$\frac{p_xp_y}{1-p_x}+\frac{p_yp_x}{1-p_y}$$  That is, either the first sample is $x$ and the first non-$x$ sample is $y$, or vice-versa.

Then we can continue similarly to compute the probabilities of visiting all the three-elements states and so on.

If $N$ is large, and $s$ is not small, this doesn't sound practical to me, and simulation might be the best approach.

**EDIT**

Parallel computation is easy, of course, but you still have to know all the probabilities.