# Finding the CDF of the Coupon Collectors Problem with non uniform probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions, coupon-collector

Given a set of $n$ coupons with draw probabilities $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i = 1$$ What is the probability $P(X \le x)$ of having completed a full set of coupons in fewer than $x$ coupons.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that with non-uniform probabilities this is a quite ugly problem. But maybe you can swing it using generating functions? I sort of doubt it though.

Comment: I am very sure it is @Ian, I am not looking for something that can be computed by hand but can be numerically approximated reasonably quickly

Comment: Numerically, as long as you can choose a reasonable cap on $x$ I think just naive MC simulation will converge pretty quickly to give you the unknown CDF values in $[0,x_{max}]$.

Comment: Alternately you can follow the inclusion-exclusion idea given in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051815/intuition-behind-the-coupon-collector-problem-is-there-inclusion-exclusion-prin?rq=1 and just evaluate the sums numerically. But there are in principle $2^n$ terms here, so this might be slow if $n$ is big.

Comment: Thank you for that link I will try it out and see if its viable to calculate the sums. I have done MC simulation for some data, I found the convergence was quite slow though, especially with the probability vectors I have, containing 150+ terms with some probabilities quite small, around 1/15,000. And since the full simulation has to be redone for a new vector it becomes quite slow. EDIT: I just saw the number of terms on that sum, so yea that is going to be completely intractable

Comment: Yeah with $n=150$ that's not gonna work unless you can safely truncate the sum (based on, e.g., ignoring all terms with more than $k$ terms excluded (which could be safe if there's a halfway decent lower bound on the $p_i$). The other problem with this method is that you have to do it all over again for each $x$, whereas in principle a MC trajectory gives you partial information about $F(x)$ for all $x$ up to the cutoff time of your simulations.

Comment: The best way is inclusion-exclusion, but it’s still not a good way. Let  $A_i$ where you fail to to get coupon $i.$

Answer (score 1):

If $I\subseteq \{1,2,\dots n\},$ then define $$p(I)=\sum_{i\in I}p_i.$$

Then inclusion-exclusion gives you:

$$P(X\leq x)=\sum_{I\subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}} (-1)^{|I|}(1-p(I))^x$$

This is not an easy formula - it requires $2^n$ terms. But you probably cannot do better.

The formula is much simpler for $p_i=\frac1n$ then $p(I)=\frac{|I|}n.$ Then you can group terms by size and get:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nk \left(\frac{n-k}n\right)^x$$

If coupon $i$ is much rarer than the others, you can probably estimate it, for $x$ large, with:

$$1-(1-p_i)^x$$

If there are $k$ coupons with probability $p$ and $n-k$ coupons with probability $q,$ with $kp+(n-k)q=1,$ then:

$$P(X\leq x)=\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}(-1)^{i+j}\binom{k}{i}\binom{n-k}j(1-ip-jq)^x$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a fencepost error in the sign flipping; the probability that coupon $i$ is excluded (when $|I|=1$) should have a $+$ sign here, I think. Unless $\emptyset$ is one of the subsets, maybe? But I don't think it is supposed to be.

Comment: Yes, emptyset is a term. @jan it should be $1-\sum$ where the sum does not include the empty set.

Comment: I see, and then that term gives you $1$. Makes sense, fixes the sanity check with the $n=1$ case that was confusing me. In that case I think the answer I linked in the comments is wrong, albeit on the right track.

Comment: The signs in that link are also correct. The probability and expected value are different. @Ian

Comment: thank you i can see this is correct based on small cases, but it is intractable for the size of problem I am trying to work on. The estimation you posted is a decent one I've used in the past, but it doesn't work for a significant portion of my sets. Hopefully there is another method or at least a more accurate (if complex) approximation

Comment: I was talking about the $P(E_t)$ expression but you're right, there is a complement operation relative to this context.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that for the general sum over the $2^{n}$ subsets the probabilities don't even need to sum to 1 for this method to work

Comment: Which probabilities? The $p_i?$ @Calisto1988

Comment: yes @ThomasAndrews

Comment: In that case, the problem becomes equivalent to “sometimes you don’t get any coupon,” with probability $1-\sum p_i.$ @Calisto1988  This formula works in that case, still.