# Expected number of rolls of a fair, 6-sided die before all the evens OR all the odds are rolled, whichever happens first.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

We're playing a game where we roll a fair, 6-sided dice over and over. The game ends when we have rolled all of the evens (2, 4, 6) OR all of the odds (1, 3, 5), we don't care which. On average how many rolls does it take to end the game? If we cared about even or odd, I think the answer would be 11 (for either scenario). I wrote a short Python script to simulate the game and believe the answer is 7.3, but I'm looking for an exact solution derived from probability theory.

Comment: This will be a messy inclusion-exclusion question, I think.

Comment: You could set this up as an absorbing markov chain with 10 or fewer states (*depending on how efficient you wish to be*).  Doing so will be tedious, but certainly doable with minimal thought required.  The fundamental of the matrix will give you information you want.

Comment: I suggest:  label states by the number of evens and odds you still have to see.  Thus $(a,b)$ means you still haven't seen $a$ evens and $b$ odds.  You start in $(3,3)$.  Transitions are easily computed.  It's a bit tedious because there are $9$ active states (and a couple terminal ones) but it isn't hard.

Comment: With regards to mine and lulu's suggestions, you could simplify this by not treating the pairs $(a,b)$ as specifically always number of evens seen (*or yet to go as the case may be*) followed by number of odds, but rather as whichever is larger.  There is also no point in having the first state be where nothing has been rolled.  Just start with $(1,0)$ and note in your head that a die roll was necessary at the start to get there.  We have then states $(1,0),(2,0),(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)$ and *end*, knocking it down to a more manageable 6-state markov chain.

Comment: This answers the generalization of your question to a $2m$-sided die: [Expected number of elements before 1 out of 2 hash tables are full?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051328/expected-number-of-elements-before-1-out-of-2-hash-tables-are-full)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a [markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) with states $(a,b)$ where $a$ is the number of the more frequently seen parity, and $b$ is number of the less frequently seen.  (*In the case of a tie, just repeat the number*) as well as the state "*end*" to mark that the game has finished.

Further, ignore the state $(0,0)$.  We will just start tracking after the first roll has already occurred since $(0,0)$ would otherwise move to state $(1,0)$ with $100\%$ probability.

Set up the corresponding absorbing markov matrix where the corresponding entries refer to the probability of moving from their corresponding column-state to their corresponding row-state.  For example, moving from the state $(2,1)$ to the end state occurs specifically when we get that last missing odd number (*if odds were in the lead, the last corresponding even number otherwise*) and so occurs with probability $\frac{1}{6}$.

> *N.B.*: Some authors prefer to use the transpose, where rows add up to $1$ instead and where states are represented as row-vectors, using $v_1M=v_2$.  The theory is the same, just everything is sideways.

The columns and rows are labeled for convenience, and the order chosen to label the columns and rows in are also chosen for convenience to make upper triangular.

$$M=\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}&\color{grey}{\text{from end}}&\color{grey}{\text{from (2,2)}}&\color{grey}{\text{from (2,1)}}&\color{grey}{\text{from (2,0)}}&\color{grey}{\text{from (1,1)}}&\color{grey}{\text{from (1,0)}}
\\\hline
\color{grey}{\text{to end}}&1&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{6}&0&0
\\\hline
\color{grey}{\text{to (2,2)}}&0&\frac{2}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&0&0&0
\\\hline
\color{grey}{\text{to (2,1)}}&0&0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{2}{3}&0
\\\hline
\color{grey}{\text{to (2,0)}}&0&0&0&\frac{1}{3}&0&\frac{1}{3}
\\\hline
\color{grey}{\text{to (1,1)}}&0&0&0&0&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{2}
\\\hline
\color{grey}{\text{to (1,0)}}&0&0&0&0&0&\frac{1}{6}
\\\hline
\end{array}$$

Perform a sanity check that the columns all add up to $1$ as expected.

This is an absorbing markov matrix in the block form $$M=\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline I&S\\\hline 0&R\\\hline\end{array}$$

From theory of markov chains, we know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} M^n = \begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline I&S(I-R)^{-1}\\\hline 0&0\\\hline\end{array}$ and that $(I-R)^{-1}$, the "*fundamental*" of the matrix, will contain information pertaining to expected wait time until arriving at an end-state.

The fundamental matrix here [after calculations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse%28%5B%5B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%5D+-+%5B%5B2%2F3%2C1%2F3%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2F2%2C1%2F2%2C2%2F3%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C1%2F3%2C0%2C1%2F3%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2F3%2C1%2F2%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2F6%5D%5D%29) will be:

$$(I_5-R)^{-1}=\frac{1}{10}\begin{bmatrix}30&20&15&20&18\\0&20&15&20&18\\0&0&15&0&6\\0&0&0&15&9\\0&0&0&0&12\end{bmatrix}$$

These numbers in the fundamental matrix correspond to the expected amount of time additional time spent in each row-state before having made it to an end state if having started in a corresponding column-state.

As we are "starting" in state $(1,0)$ our expected wait time until arriving at an end state will be $\dfrac{18+18+6+9+12}{10} = 6.3$

Finally, remembering that we had a die roll at the very start to enter the $(1,0)$ state gives us a final answer of exactly

$$7.3$$

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you so much!

Comment: Why is that marked a spoiler?

Comment: For this answer to be complete, you should mention the beautiful generalization to a $2m$-sided die numbered $1$ to $2m$. The average time it takes to get all evens or odds is $4m H_m-2mH_{2m}$, where $H_m$ is the $m^\text{th}$ Harmonic number. This can be proved as a simple consequence to the coupon collectors problem, as I mentioned in my answer to this earlier duplicate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4051328/

Comment: @MikeEarnest is there a way to generalize the answer to that question to completing the first of $n$ many hash tables? For example, for $n = 3$, can WhatsUps first equation from that question be modified to: $$E(a, b, c) = 1 + \frac a {3m}E(a - 1, b, c) + \frac b {3m} E(a, b - 1, c) + \frac c {3m} E(a, b, c - 1) + (1 - \frac{a + b + c}{3m})E(a, b, c)$$ and is there a good way to solve this for $F(m, m, m)$? I can ask as a new question if that's best.

Comment: @Imperator Yes, it generalizes nicely! It takes some effort to explain, so it would be best to post a new question.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I asked the new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4659807/expected-number-of-elements-for-the-first-of-n-many-hash-tables-to-be-filled

Answer (score 2):

Using JMoravitz idea of shortening the number of states, but using First Step Analysis rather than a Markov matrix computation,

Let us label the states $(1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)$
as states $a,b,c,d,e$ respectively, then the state equations will be

$\displaylines{a=1+a/6+3b/6+2c/6\\ b = 1+2b/6+4d/6 \\ c= 1+2c/6+3d/6 \\ d = 1+3d/6+2e/6 \\ e = 1+4e/6}$

[Note that  the equations where the probabilities fall short of of $1$ indicate that that with the last step, the end has been reached]

[Solving the system of linear equations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%3D1%2Ba%2F6%2B3b%2F6%2B2c%2F6%2C+b+%3D+1%2B2b%2F6%2B4d%2F6%2C+c%3D+1%2B2c%2F6%2B3d%2F6%2C+d+%3D+1%2B3d%2F6%2B2e%2F6%2C+e+%3D+1%2B4e%2F6), we get $a = 6.3 \;\;$
and adding the initial first step ignored for simplification,
the answer is $\boxed{7.3}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $N_k$ be the number of rolls when you get the $k$th distinct results. Then we get $$\begin{align} 
E(N_3)&=1+\frac65+\frac64=\frac{37}{10}\\
E(N_4)&=\frac{37}{10}+\frac63=\frac{57}{10}\\
E(N_5)&=\frac{57}{10}+\frac62=\frac{87}{10}
\end{align}$$

The probability that your game is over on the third distinct value is $\frac{2}{\binom63}=\frac1{10},$ on the fourth distinct value, $\frac13\frac9{10}=\frac3{10},$ and in the fifth distinct value $\frac6{10}.$

So the expected value is:

$$\frac1{10}E(N_3)+\frac{3}{10}E(N_4)+\frac{6}{10} E(N_5)=\frac{73}{10}$$

I initially thought this was too high, but really, more than half the time, you need to get five distinct values, and that has an expected number of turns $\frac{87}{10}.$ So not too large at all.

---

I got this value from an inclusion-exclusion argument, that at roll $k$ the probability that you have *not* finished is:

$$p_k=\sum_{i,j=1}^3(-1)^{i+j}\binom{3}{i}\binom3j\left(\frac{6-i-j}6\right)^k$$

Then your expected value is:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty p_k=\sum_{i,j=1}^{3}(-1)^{i+j}\binom3i\binom3j\frac6{i+j}$$

That is, obviously, a more complicated argument, but it also returned $\frac{73}{10}.$

The inclusion-exclusion argument can be more easily extended to two disjoint sets of values $A,B$ with respective sizes $a,b$ and a uniform selection from $A\cup B,$ to get:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{a}\sum_{j=1}^{b}(-1)^{i+j}\binom{a}{i}\binom{b}j\frac{a+b}{i+j}\tag1$$

Or even a multiplayer version, with disjoint sets $A_j$, $j=1,2,\dots,n$ of size $a_j$ and $a=\sum a_j,$ then the expected number of turns is:

$$\sum_{i_1}^{a_1}\cdots\sum_{i_n=1}^{a_n}(-1)^{\sum (i_j-1)}\binom{a_1}{i_1}\cdots\binom{a_n}{i_n}\frac{a}{\sum i_j}$$

---

One way to look at $(1)$ is to that if $$f(x)=\left(1-(1-x)^a\right)\left(1-(1-x)^b\right)=1-(1-x)^a-(1-x)^b+(1-x)^{a+b}$$ then the coefficient of $x^{k}$ is $$(-1)^k\sum_{i=1}^{a}\binom{a}{i}\binom{b}{k-i}_*$$ where the $*$ alters the binomial to be $0$ when $k-i=0.$ This sum is exactly the coefficient of $\frac{a+b}{k}$ in $(1).$

Assume $a\leq b.$

The coefficient of $x^k$ is:

$$\begin{cases}0&k=0\\
(-1)^k\left(\binom{a+b}{k}-\binom{a}{k}-\binom bk\right)&k>0
\end{cases}.$$

So the expexted value is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{a+b}(-1)^k\left(\binom{a+b}{k}-\binom ak -\binom bk\right)\frac{a+b}{k}$$

Looking at this, it seems likely we can prove this directly with inclusion-exclusion.

That gives $\frac{73}{10}$ again when $a=b=3.$

Comment: How did you work the the probabilities that the game would end on the third, fourth and fifth distinct values?

Comment: At the third turn, you only win if the first three distinct values were all even or all odd. So that 8s two cases out of the $\binom{6}{3}$ equally likely possible subset of $3,$ for $\frac1{10}.$ If not, you got two of one kind and one of the other, so one third of the time, when you get a new number, you get a match for the pair and thus $\frac13\left(1-\frac1{10}\right)=\frac3{10}.$ someone always wins by the fifth turn. @Imperator

Comment: Okay, thank you, very much. Your answer is quite intuitive, very elegant.

Comment: Any ideas as to how you would apply your first argument to multiple sets, say if we rolled a 20-sided die and the sets ending the game were (1-5), (6-10), etc.? I think the probability of the 5th distinct value ending the game would then be $\frac{4}{{20}\choose{5}}$ , but I don't know where to go with larger distinct values. And I think the Markov chain method used above would run into trouble with the matrix being impractically large.

Comment: @Imperator Yeah, this approach won't work easily for more players, or if the players have have unequal sets. You have to consider too many cases. It can be done, but it is non-trivia. In the end, you will be doing the recursive solution others have provided. But the inclusion-exclusion argument handles these cases. I think, in the twenty-sided die divided up into four players equally, you get: $$\sum_{k=1}^{20}(-1)^k\left(\binom{20}{k}-\binom4{1}\binom{15}{k}+\binom42\binom{10}k-\binom{4}3\binom5k\right)\frac{20}{k}$$

Comment: That will almost certainly be faster than solving a set of linear equations in $27+$ variables.

Comment: Actually, my first technique does even work well for an eight-sided die and two players, because it can fail to end at the fourth distinct digit in two different ways. Basically, figuring out odd of ending on the $n$th turn is harder in those cases.

Comment: In the two-player version, I suppose the probabilities aren't that hard. If the die has $2n$ sides, the probability that someone wins on the $n$th distinct roll is $\frac2{\binom{2n}2}.$ For $n<k<2n-1,$ the probability of ending on the $k$th round is the probability of having $n-1$ for one player in the previous digit, which is $$\frac{2\binom{n}{n-1}\binom{n}{k-n}}{\binom{2n}{k}}$$ times the probability that the next round will finish it out, $\frac{1}{2n-k+1}.$ Giving $$\frac{2n\binom n{k-n}}{(2n-k+1)\binom{2n}k}$$

Comment: Could you explain how you worked out the equation for $p_k$ in your inclusion-exclusion argument?

Comment: @Imperator It was tricky, because it isn't a "simple" inclusion-exclusion. Officially, we let $A$ be all rolls of $k$ dice, and $A_{i,j}$ be the rolls that miss $i$ odd and $j$ even. You can do that and get this result, but it is messy. I actually did a "generalized Möbius inversion" instead, which is a generalization of inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $T$ is the number of the roll on which we first get a full set of even numbers or a full set of odd numbers.  We want to find $E(T)$.

The exponential generating function (EGF) for the probability that we have a full set of even numbers on the $n$th roll (not necessarily for the first time) is $e^{x/2} (e^{x/6}-1)^3$, which
is also the EGF for the probability that we have a full set of odd numbers. The EGF for the probability that we have full sets of both even and odd numbers is $(e^{x/6}-1)^6$. So by inclusion/exclusion, the EGF for the probability that we have either a full set of even numbers or a full set of odd numbers on the $n$th roll is
$$f(x) = 2 e^{x/2} (e^{x/6}-1)^3 - (e^{x/6}-1)^6 \tag{*}$$
(the probability of odds plus the probability of evens minus the probability of both). Another way to look at $f(x)$ is that it is the EGF for $P( T \le n)$.  The complementary event is $P(T > n)$, so its EGF is $e^x - f(x)$; i.e.,
$$e^x - f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{P(T>n)}{n!} x^n$$

By a well-known theorem,
$$E(T) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(T>n)$$
Making use of the identity $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x^n \; dx = n!$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(T>n) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} (e^x-f(x)) \; dx$$
where $f(x)$ is given by $(*)$.  It shouldn't be hard to evaluate the integral by hand, but I used Mathematica, with the result
$$E(T) = \frac{73}{10}$$

Comment: I think your method would give a very nice answer to [this generalized question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4659807/expected-number-of-elements-for-the-first-of-n-many-hash-tables-to-be-filled), perhaps you are interested.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you, that does look interesting.